# jQuery: Count specific character in a table column

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table where each row has two columns. First column is a capital letter and the second one is a brand name, like so:

A | Amazon

A | Apple

B | BMW

C | Chanel

etc. But whenever there are two brand names that has the same first capital letter I would like the table to look like this:

A | Amazon

| Apple

B | BMW

C | Chanel

In other words, if there are more than one instance of each capital letter I would like to display only the first one. If I applied a class to the first column, is there a way I could achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Can you modify the HTML to add a class to each row? If you can, you might be able to achieve a non-js solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function (assuming the class of your first column is `leftCol`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastLetter = "";
    $(".leftCol").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();
        if (text != lastLetter) {
            lastLetter = text;
        } else {
            $this.text("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class you give to the first column is called 'letter':

```
var previousLetter = null;
$('table td.letter').each(function(i, el){
    var currentLetter = el.innerHTML;
    if (currentLetter == previousLetter) el.innerHTML = '';
    previousLetter = currentLetter;
});
```

Although, you don't have to assign a special class for this, you can just the same use `$('table td:first-child')`

Of course, these solutions assume only one table in the page, so it would be wiser to give your table an id and use `$('#myTable td:first-child')`