# Extract specific information from html tables?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with some tables like this:

```
<html>
<ol>
<li>entry1</li>
<li>entry2</li>
<li>entry3</li>
<li>entry4</li>
</ol>   
</html>
```

I now want to count the occurences of "entry" on the page, and also to extract in which line of the table it is each placed (here  1st line).

Are there java tools to accomplish this task? For searching the count, I would use a RegEx and Matcher Pattern.
But how can I best extract the table row from that document?

Comment: try this link from SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378407/jquery-count-specific-character-in-a-table-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this, it is very easy to extract information from HTML with it.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to use additional libraries you could use regular expressions http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: @LeeTaylor if I could +10 I would :)